# Sqlite no such table error

Tags: android, sqlite

I am getting a table not found error. I googled a lot but not able to found the source of the error

```
public class update extends Activity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.update);
        Button upbtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.upbutton);
        final EditText detedit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.upedit);
        final EditText amtedit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        stdb obj=new stdb(this);
        final SQLiteDatabase dobj=obj.getWritableDatabase();
        upbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            String setdet,setamt;
            setdet=detedit.getText().toString();
            setamt=amtedit.getText().toString();
            //try{

            String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO " +stdb.tname+" (" + stdb.details+" , "+stdb.amt+") VALUES("+setdet+" , "+setamt+");";

            //Log.e("sql",insertQuery);

            dobj.execSQL(insertQuery);
            //}
            //catch(SQLException e ){
            //  Log.e("sqlite",e.toString());

            //}

        }
    });


    }

}
```

SQLiteOpenHelper:

```
public class stdb extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int version = 1;
    public static final String dname = "statments.db";
    public static final String tname="transactions";
    public static final String sid = "sno";
    public static final String details = "details";
    public static final String amt = "amount";

    public stdb(Context context) {
        super(context, dname, null, version);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String ex="CREATE TABLE " + tname + " (" + sid + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + details+ " VARCHAR(255),"+amt+" INTEGER);";
        Log.e("ex",ex );

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + tname + " (" + sid + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + details+ " VARCHAR(255),"+amt+" INTEGER);");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ tname);
        onCreate(db);
    }

}
```

Comment: @John Conde thanks for editing

Comment: Refer this [link](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html) to solve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try incrementing the version number:

```
private static final int version = 2;
```

I'm guessing that you changed your `CREATE TABLE` statement at some point, but the system won't know about these changes automatically. The easiest way to update your schema is to add 1 to `version`.

**Also**

You shouldn't use [execSQL()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL%28java.lang.String%29) for `INSERT` commands, use insert():

```
ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
initialValues.put(stbd.details, setdet);
initialValues.put(stbd.amt, setamt);
dobj.insert(stbd.tname, null, initialValues);
```

Or rawQuery():

```
String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO " +stdb.tname+" (" + stdb.details+" , "+stdb.amt+") VALUES(?, ?);";
dobj.rawQuery(insertQuery, new String[] {setdet, setamt});
```